# Eclipse is not responding

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have 3 application , one is running at Jre 1.4 , second one is at 1.6 and third one is at jre 1.7.
Now after restarting my computer , eclipse is not getting started.I download new eclipse also , but every time splash screen of eclipse prompt for once and then it will not getting started.

I tried almost every thing , i edited eclipse.ini file with -vm argument and path till bin
eg :--vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin
But still it is  not responding.

I am pasting my eclipse.ini file

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile

-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Even i uninstall jdk and install it again , but not get the solution.

It would be great for  some one guide me what to do.

**P.S :- I am working in window xp, and before restarting everything was working fine**

Comment: `-vm` and `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin` **must** be on separate lines.

Comment: Thanks greg449 , it helped. Can u plz add this as a answer, so i can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each entry in the `eclipse.ini` file must be on a separate line.

So you need `-vm` and `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin` on separate lines.

They must also come before the `-vmargs` line since everything after that is taken to be a VM argument.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is about java path;

I am using Windows 7:

This PC >> Properties >> Advanced System Settings >> Environment Variables... >>

in system variables find "**path**" and change java path or add your jdk path.

Answer (score 0):

The value for the -vm switch is supposed to be the Java executable itself, not the folder containing it. It should be on the line following -vm, and be `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\javaw.exe` rather than `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin`.